# How to let the angular compiler know about type definitions added by a npm/cordova plugin?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my Ionic/Angular project I am using [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin). It has included [type definitions](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/types/index.d.ts) and when I work with it in vscode I see how them are recognized.

[image: autocomplete in vscode]

The problem I have if that the angular compiler does not find them. For example, using:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaEmail();
```

will throw an error:

> Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window'.

If I try to map it like

```
const socialsharing: SocialSharing = (window as any).plugins.socialsharing;
```

I get

> Cannot find name 'SocialSharing'.

How can I let Angular/Ionic know those types (that live in `node_modules/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/types/index.d.ts`) ?

Comment: you can try using typeRoots in tsconfig.json

Comment: Are you using angularJs or angular Ts ? Since if you are using ts , you can just declare the plugin in constructor and call its functions.

Comment: @MostafaHarb TS, but I do not want to re declare them, I just want to let Angular know they already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the solution was to add new file in my `src` folder with a triple slash reference to the types file

typings.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing/types/index.d.ts" />
```

Now it works!